# SQLAlchemy 1.4.0b1 AsyncSession issue

Tags: asynchronous, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy 1.4.0b1's AsyncSession to update a Postgres db with asyncpg 0.21.0.   The code below aims to update objects and add new objects in response to various incoming Redis stream messages

The save_revised coroutine (update) is working fine, and so is the session.add part of the td_move coroutine.    However the update part of td_move, at the bottom of the function (starting from `if this_train_id and msg.get('from') in finals[crossing]`) , only works intermittently : I'm getting some db updates but only ~1/3 or so of the log messages indicating that an update is wanted.

Can anyone suggest what the problem(s) could be please ?

```
async def main():
    logger.info(f"db_updater starting {datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}")
    engine = create_async_engine(os.getenv('ASYNC_DB_URL'), future=True)

    async with AsyncSession(engine) as session:

        crossings, headcodes, lean_params, finals, active_trains, train_ids, berthtimes, hc_types = await get_db_data(logger)  # noqa: E501
        pool = await aioredis.create_redis_pool(('redis', 6379), db=0, password=os.getenv('REDIS_PW'), encoding='utf-8')

        last_id = '$'
        while True:
            all_msgs = await pool.xread(['del_hc_s', 'xing_revised', 'all_td', 'add_hc_s'], latest_ids=[last_id, last_id, last_id, last_id])  # noqa: E501
            for stream_name, msg_id, msg in all_msgs:
                message = dict(msg)
                crossing = message.get('crossing')

                if stream_name == 'all_td':
                    await td_move(message, train_ids, active_trains, finals, lean_params, session)

                elif stream_name == 'xing_revised':
                    await save_revised(message, lean_params[crossing], session)


async def save_revised(msg, params, session):
    train_id = msg.get('train_id')
    # today_class is a SQLA model class from declarative_base()
    today_class = params['today_class']
    rev_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(
        int(msg.get('revised')))
    stmt = update(today_class).where(today_class.train_id == train_id).\
        values(xing_revised=rev_time).\
        execution_options(synchronize_session="fetch")
    await session.execute(stmt)
    if msg.get('revised_ten') != 'X':
        stmt2 = update(today_class).where(today_class.train_id == train_id).\
            values(xing_revised_ten=rev_time).\
            execution_options(synchronize_session="fetch")
        await session.execute(stmt2)

    await session.commit()


async def td_move(msg, train_ids, active_trains, finals, params, session):
    crossing = msg.get('crossing')
    descr = msg.get('descr')
    if crossing:
        this_train_id = [s for s in train_ids[crossing] if descr in s]
        if this_train_id:
            this_train_id = this_train_id[0]
    else:
        return
    if this_train_id and active_trains[crossing].get(this_train_id) and (
            is_within_minutes(30, active_trains[crossing].get(this_train_id))):
        # Td_Ca_Cc is a SQLA model class from declarative_base()
        td = Td_Ca_Cc(
            msg_type=msg.get('msg_type'),
            descr=msg.get('descr'),
            traintype=active_trains[crossing].get(
                this_train_id).get('train_type'),
            from_berth=msg.get('from'),
            to_berth=msg.get('to'),
            tdtime=dt_from_timestamp(msg.get('time')),
            seconds=0,
            area_id=msg.get('area_id'),
            updated=datetime.now(),
            crossing=crossing
        )
        session.add(td)
    if this_train_id and msg.get('from') in finals[crossing]:
        today_class = params[crossing]['today_class']
        stmt = update(today_class).where(today_class.train_id == this_train_id).\
            values(xing_actual=datetime.now(), cancel_time='XXX').\
            execution_options(synchronize_session="fetch")
        await session.execute(stmt)
        logger.info(f"{crossing} {msg.get('descr')} passed {datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}")
        await session.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference the problem was making a (sync) logging call.    I removed this (and will add an async logger call), the modified code is now working fine